# Does the source_elapsed in a CQL trace output show when a command starts or finishes?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

On the official DataStax page https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html, it is not very clear what the source_elapsed is trying to say in regards to individuals commands.

Say for example, if we wanted to know when the "submitted 1 concurrent range" is finished (within the link above), would it be at the timestamp 3002 to 3130?

If it was 3002, would we then say it took 3002-1632 time to complete? Obviously can switch the numbers up but just wanted some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source_elapsed` is the time in microseconds that have gone by since the beginning of the query trace.

> If it was 3002, would we then say it took 3002-1632 time to complete?

Yes, that is correct.  So the "submitted 1 concurrent range" operation took 1370 microseconds or 1.37 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, the CQL command in the example was:

```
SELECT * FROM cycling.cyclist_name;
```

Whereas "Preparing statement" and "Submitted 1 concurrent range requests" are activities of the CQL request.

The `source_elapsed` in the trace output is the elapsed time for each **activity** in a CQL request, not command. You can think of it as the equivalent of the elapsed time for each lap in a stopwatch.

Using this abridged version of the example:

```
 activity                                            | source_elapsed
-----------------------------------------------------+----------------
                                  Execute CQL3 query |              0
          Parsing SELECT * FROM cycling.cyclist_name |            372
                                 Preparing statement |            541
                           Computing ranges to query |            807
         Submitting range requests on 257 ranges ... |           1632
               Submitted 1 concurrent range requests |           3002
 Executing seq scan across 1 sstables for (..., ...] |           3130
                   Read 6 live and 0 tombstone cells |           3928
                                    Request complete |           4252
```

it took:

- 372 microseconds (µs) to parse the CQL statement
- 169 µs (`541 - 372`) to prepare the statement
- 266 µs (`807 - 541`) to compute ranges to query

and so on.

If you were trying to diagnose why a query is taking a long time, the elapsed time from the trace output gives you an indication of which step was the biggest contributor. Cheers!